# Delete function is not working

Tags: php, sql

I am doing a system with php code,But delete function with SQL is not working.I don't know why it happens.

Below is my code:

```
function deleteEmployee($params)
{
    $tid = $_SESSION['tmid'];
    $data = array();
    //print_R($_POST);die;
    $sql = "delete from `cusinfo` WHERE TICKET_ID='".$params["id"]."' AND AGENT_CODE_STAFF_ID IN (SELECT id FROM `users` where tm_groupid = '$tid')";
    echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to delete employee data");
}
```

Comment: "cannot works" is not a problem description. _Why_ doesn't it work?

Comment: replace the `die` string with `mysqli_error($this->conn)`. It should tell you if there is a mysql error

Comment: @Jelmergu , It still show nothing while I click delete

Comment: @Jelmergu , Sorry , you have solve my problem.I just replace die with `mysqli_error($this->conn)` , then it work properly

Comment: Thankyou for helping me:)

Comment: it didn't give a error? Do note though that the or might have unexpected results. After trying `echo $test = "hello" or die("test");` there was a 1(true) displayed on the screen! not hello or test, meaning that your problem could still be unresolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably is in the line `echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to delete employee data");`

As I said in one comment, replacing the `die` string with mysqli_error($this->conn) should display an error.

However after some testing I found that assigning a variable in a echo might give strange results, i test `echo $test = "hello" or die("test");` and found that neither `hello` nor `test` was displayed on the screen, but `1` was displayed, which probably was the boolean true.

A better way to see if the query was executed could be:

```
    //other code that stayed the same
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($this->conn, "delete from `cusinfo` WHERE TICKET_ID=? AND AGENT_CODE_STAFF_ID IN (SELECT id FROM `users` where tm_groupid = ?)");
    $statement = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($this->conn, $params['id'], $tid); //
    $sql = msyqli_stmt_execute($statement); // returns either true or false
    if ($sql === true) {

        echo "Successfull"; // executing successfull code
    }
    else {
        var_dump(mysqli_stmt_error_list($statement)); // handling error
        die;
    }
```

This will handle some sql errors in a way that is expected(they are 'dumped and died').

Using prepared statements the correct way will mean that most sql injections are able to be stopped, and with a DELETE query, you want to make sure that sql injections are stopped.

Note: I am no expert on sql injections
Note 2: I would have used PDO for prepared statements though, it seems to me to be much more logical to work with

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to delete employee data");
```

In above line you are execution query and `echo` it. But if it is not executed you are `echo` your own message. This will prevent you from actual error message. And if the row that you are going to delete from `TICKET_ID` not exsist you cannot see it, you only see your message `"error to delete employee data"`.

To solve this:

```
echo mysqli_error($this->conn);
```

This will give you connection error.

Or:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
if ($result) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Many many function have to handle these errors. [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments), [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-error.php) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp).

Comment: you should edit the PHP manual link to go to `mysqli_error` and not to a deprecated `mysql_error`

Comment: @Jelmergu: thanks man!